# Google Analytics 4 does not show data (realtime/debugview)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm using google analytics 4 in my test website made with WordPress. I have successfully configured Google Tag and connect GA4 with my website.

I have a situation where i have an event tag sent to GA4 account but i cant see anything neither in real-time reports nor in my debug view. Other event such as page_view and User engagement appear like normal.

These are the events:

[image]

And they are fired successfully as you can see:

[image]

[image]

The measurement ID is correct and the connection is valid and there is no internal filter set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Some of your screenshots are fine, but the ones with your code in them should be entered as text instead.